# Can we use JPA Repository to pull/fetch data from Mysql View? If yes How?

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-boot-jpa

I have many tables where I am using JPARepository to fetch data from it. Then I have created on MySql - View and tried to use JPARepository to do findAll but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native query and a DTO projection:

```
public interface ReportRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM yourView")
   List<YourDto> getDateFromYourView();

}
```

Comment: I will try and update. but Based on your answer new question rise in my mind can we JPA Criteria on Views?